# Unable to connect to Windows VPN from iPad

Tags: networking, vpn, apple, ipad

I have a 16 GB iPad wifi I can't get to connect to VPN. The error I get is:
"A connection could not be established to the PP server. Try reconnecting. If the problem continues, verify your settings and contact your Administrator."

I have tried a variety of tasks to troubleshoot the issue:

- I have verified that another iPad on another network can connect to the VPN I am trying to connect to
- I can connect to this VPN from the same network the iPad uses on a Windows machine
- I have verified an iPhone user can connect to this VPN from a different network
- I have reset the iPad's network settings
- I have reset the entire iPad and restored settings
- I have compared my settings w/ a screenshot from the iPad that works and confirmed everything is correct
- I have used the IP address and domain name of our VPN server in the settings
- I have tried deleting the VPN settings in the iPad and recreating them
- I have verified in the logs of VPN server that I'm not even getting to the VPN server (no log entry)
- I have verified that I cannot VPN from the iPad on separate network (different ISP and router)

Are there any other ways to troubleshoot VPN on an iPad?

Comment: Sounds like you have tried a lot of various scenarios.  At this point you may need to watch the connection with tcpdump or some other capture tool.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to do this over 3G, be aware that AT&T's network will block VPN access (outbound) unless you have their Enterprise Data Plan.

Comment: Clarified. This is a wifi iPad.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be NAT traversal problem? You mentioned 'separate network' I'm assuming that the iPhone VPN and iPad VPN have been tested on wifi from the same 'separate network'. That would rule out NAT traversal if the iPhone connected. Otherwise, as I read it, if your 'different network' and 'separate network' mentioned above are different networks, it should be a local configuration issue. If that makes sense...

*Side note: apparently I don't have enough to comment on pjz's post, but as a clarification I run VPN over 3G with no trouble whatsoever (and non-enterprise AT&T account).*